# Apache httpd active/passive setup

Tags: apache-2.2, load-balancing, cluster

I want to setup apache web server in active passive mode to support HTTP failover on Redhat linux 5 machine.
I understand that 2 Linux boxes can be setup in HA using heartbeat or keepalived. Also, RHEL comes with add on packge for Network load balancing.
Wanted to know -
1. any other consideration I need to make in order to have highly available site
2. what are pros and cons of options heartbeat, keepalived, RHEL package

Comment: Can you clarify what you're looking to achieve?  It's hard to recommend a solution without knowing what problems you're facing.

Comment: We have developed a Java web application on JBoss application server. We will be using Apache web server to serve static HTTP content and JBoss will serve dynamic content. Deployed solution should be highly available, that is with failover capability. Application does not have much HTTP load and hence as per our calculation one web server should be able to handle it. But there should be failover for this web server. We are trying to have setup in which if this Apache web server goes down or physical machine goes down then another web server on second machine takes over.